# Text is centre aligned on computer and phone simulator, but not on actual phone?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is from bootstrap, but what I am trying to do is add a fig caption below an image that is center aligned for only smaller screens. When I check on my computer and shrink the window, the fig caption appears and is center aligned, when i check the code on a phone simulator (for example iphone5), it is also center aligned, **but when I then upload the file to the server and check my phone (which is an iphone5)**, the text is not center aligned like on the simulator, but is instead left aligned. So my question is what is causing this error, and how do I fix it to be center aligned.

Also, I have the footer coded in a way to disappear on smaller screens. It is the same issue as above. It disappears when i shrink the window or when I check on the phone simulator, but it doesn't disappear on the actual phone.

Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="padding: 0px;">
          <img src="example.jpg" style="max-width:100%; margin-top: 48px;" alt="example"></img>
          <figcaption>Details</figcaption>

        </div>

<footer class="footer" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Details</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {
  figcaption {
    display: none;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  figcaption {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the closing brackets around your `@media` queries.

Should be:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {
  figcaption {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  figcaption {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But, instead of doing it manually, you could use the [Bootstrap responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). To do what you're looking for:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="padding: 0px;">
    <img src="example.jpg" style="max-width:100%; margin-top: 48px;" alt="example"></img>
    <figcaption class="visible-xs-block text-center">Details</figcaption>
</div>

<footer class="footer hidden-xs" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Details</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Wow amazing! Thank you very much! And do you think that using the bootstrap classes would be a better solution?

Comment: I think it would be better to use the Bootstrap classes whenever possible because they've already done the hard work for you. (Also, I've updated my comment to add one more class to the `<figcaption>` to give you centered text)

Answer (score 0):

```
i have add bootstrap class text-center in figcaption below plz refer it 


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="padding: 0px;">
    <img src="example.jpg" style="max-width:100%; margin-top: 48px;" alt="example"></img>
    <figcaption class="visible-xs-block text-center">Details</figcaption>
</div>

<footer class="footer hidden-xs" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Details</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```